# How do you get Kyogre in Omega Ruby?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

Like the title states, I would like to get Kyogre on my copy of Omega Ruby, but I don't know how.

How do I catch or otherwise get Kyogre in Omega Ruby?

Answer (score 5):

The only way to obtain [Kyogre](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Kyogre_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29#Game_locations) in Omega Ruby is through trading, or through a distribution event.

Answer (score -4):

You can use either Pokemon Bank or you can get a copy of Alpha and play all the way to Kyogre and transfer Kyogre all the way to Omega Ruby but I really doubt that you would really wanna replay the whole game again for a Kyogre.